# How to parse string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ykkJMX3C)):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.promocode 
(
    promo_name varchar(100)
);

INSERT dbo.promocode (promo_name) 
VALUES ('(Web) promo addf 2000 from 4000, 2500 from 5000, 3000 from 6000'),
       ('(CPA Partners) promo abc2a% 200 from 2000, 1000 from 2000'),
       ('(CPA) promo sdafg1300 1300 from 6000');
```

I need to remove the first 3 "constructions" from those strings.

- constructions1 - everything inside parens `()` (could be any number of words)
- constructions2 - word1
- constructions3 - word2 (may contain numbers, `%`, etc.)

I am trying to get these results:

```
2000 from 4000, 2500 from 5000, 3000 from 6000
200 from 2000, 1000 from 2000 
1300 from 6000
```

I tried the following expression:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(Promo_name, CHARINDEX(' ', Promo_name, 
       CHARINDEX(' ', Promo_name, CHARINDEX(' ', Promo_name) + 1) + 1) + 1, LEN(Promo_name)) AS result
FROM 
    dbo.promocode;
```

But [it did not get the desired result](https://dbfiddle.uk/--WSH1zp).

Comment: Find the position of the 2nd space, and remove up to there? `STUFF` will be more useful than `SUBSTRING` here.

Comment: @ 
Mark Schultheiss. no, maybe different

Comment: what is this `Promo_name` in your code? can we assume the column name?  seems to conflict with `your_column` perhaps just a paste typo

Comment: For clarity on other comment "second space after first `)` but perhaps you understood that already.

Comment: @Thom A
 It's unlikely to work with spaces, because in brackets () there may be several words separated by a space. And I need to completely remove the first 3 constructions: (word1 word2) word2 word3
(word1 word2) - first construction
word2 - second
word3 - third

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Please update your question with new information for clarification not just add comments.  Now is it **always the first numeric** - anything prior to that?

Comment: `(CPA Partners) Promo abc` = "three words"? How exactly does your definition of "words" work for this query?

Comment: Then your description in your question is incorrect, @ilil . "(are you able to) describe properly" isn't three words, it's *six*.

Comment: This mostly comes down do a design flaw in your architecture. You have violated 1NF by putting multiple values in a single tuple. If this was originally in its own column you would not be fighting to return this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on *tokenization* instead of parsing.

Notable points:

- 1st `CROSS APPLY` removes parenthesis and everything in between.
- 2nd `CROSS APPLY` is tokenizing input as XML.
- XQuery `.query()` method retrieves third word and everything after it.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, promo_name VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT @tbl (promo_name) VALUES
('(Web) promo addf 2000 from 4000, 2500 from 5000, 3000 from 6000'),
('(CPA Partners) promo abc2a% 200 from 2000, 1000 from 2000'),
('(CPA) promo sdafg1300 1300 from 6000');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT t.*
    , c.query('data(/root/r[position() ge 3])').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(1024)') AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRIM(STUFF(promo_name, 1, CHARINDEX(')', promo_name), ''))) AS t1(tokens)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t2(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | promo_name | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (Web) promo addf 2000 from 4000, 2500 from 5000, 3000 from 6000 | 2000 from 4000, 2500 from 5000, 3000 from 6000 |
| 2 | (CPA Partners) promo abc2a% 200 from 2000, 1000 from 2000 | 200 from 2000, 1000 from 2000 |
| 3 | (CPA) promo sdafg1300 1300 from 6000 | 1300 from 6000 |

Comment: *"I need to remove the first 3 words from those strings."* just going by the OP.

Comment: The OP is treating parenthesis and everything in between as "one word".

Comment: For sure, I concur.

Answer (score 0):

If we are sure we will always look for first numeric digit and we need to take everything from that, then we can look for a numeric digit and take rest of the string.

```
Declare @string nvarchar(2000)

set @string = '"(CPA Partners) Promo ddb 500 from 1000, 1000 from 2000"'


select len('"(CPA Partners) Promo ddb 5')
select patindex('%[0-9]%', @string)

Select left (@string, patindex('%[0-9]%', @string)-1)
Select Right (@string, LEN(@STRING) - patindex('%[0-9]%', @string)+1 )
```